# Паттерн MVP. В каком месте создавать WebClient?

Tags: c#

Реализую проект на паттерне MVP. Программе надо чтоб она загружала string из интернета. Где мне создавать экземпляр класса WebClient?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Скорее всего, это модельная операция.

К View это совершенно точно не имеет отношения, Presenter по идее тоже не должен заниматься «добыванием» данных. Следовательно, это, как и вся «реальная работа», принадлежит модели.